# How i can configure jobs created by Jenkins multi-branch Pipeline using declarative syntax?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

For example, I want to configure [Notification plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Notification+Plugin) for use in multi-branch Pipeline using declarative syntax. 
There's [snippet generator](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator) for that purpose providing me with code like:

```
properties([  
   [  
      $class:'HudsonNotificationProperty',
      endpoints:[  
         [  
            urlInfo:[  
               urlOrId:'https://example.com/smth',
               urlType:'PUBLIC'
            ]
         ]
      ]
   ],
   pipelineTriggers(   [  

   ]   )
])
```

I believe it's written in [Scripted Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline) syntax. How can I integrate this into my project using [Declarative Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline) syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paste your properties snippet before declare the pipeline:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

properties([[$class: 'HudsonNotificationProperty',
  endpoints: [[urlInfo: [urlOrId: 'https://foo.bar.com', urlType: 'PUBLIC']]]]]
 )

pipeline {
...
}
```

Comment: Any idea of what it takes to get this working again? It appears as `properties` is no longer supported in Declarative Pipeline Syntax since version 0.8